# operation must use an updateable query error Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a master table *tblBudget* which contains  entries like

```
ProjID Type Budget Active 
101     ROM   100      No 
101     PLE   110      No 
101     DLE   120     Yes 
102     ROM   200      No 
102     PLE   210     Yes
```

Every month I get an excel which i import and store into a temp table  *tblMonthlyBudget* that contains entries like

```
ProjID Type Budget Active 
101     EAC    100    Yes
102     DLE    110    Yes
```

I wrote an update query that tries to update all the `Active` entries in *tblBudget* to No so that new records which are the most active could then be inserted. My query is

```
UPDATE tblBudget 
INNER JOIN tblMonthlyBudget 
        ON tblBudget.ProjectId = tblMonthlyBudget.ProjectID  
SET tblBudget.Active = false
```

However I get the error

> operation must use an updateable query

even though the query seems to show correctly in the datasheet and design view. I get it only while executing the query . I tried searching for the error and have tried all sorts of combinations without success. Any alternative approach is welcome.
I suspect this is because the temporary table contains more than one records.

Comment: Normally on two source tables (no queries), such an update should work. There must something structural about these two. What do you mean by *temp table*?

Comment: Does `tblBudget` have a Primary Key? If yes, what is it?

Comment: @Andre thank you for your help. I figured out the problem based on that, i was trying to update a table based on a join with a crosstab query.  The problem was solved when i inserted the results of the crosstab query in a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your problem using the data and table structures, you provided.  But the UPDATE works as I would expect.  It will still work if there are repeated entries in tblMonthlyBudget - it just updates an excessive number of times.  Please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and alter your question with data and table structure that actually produces your error.  Otherwise we have almost zero hope of helping you.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I figured out the problem, tblMonthlyBudget is a crosstab query that transposes another table. The problem was solved when i inserted the results of the crosstab query in a temporary table. For some reason access does not allow me to update a table based on a join with a crosstab query.

Comment: Yes Access is very restrictive when updating on joins. Glad you got it fixed.